# Facing issue with async/await methods in routeconfig

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to call await method in routeconfig to change route dynamically based on the values from the Database.

Can some one please suggest how can i achieve this

Comment: `RegisterRoutes` is a synchronous method, so ideally you should access the database synchronously.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay- Thanks for response.I am trying to override default route and create new url based on the value from the DB.We are using asynchronous calls at api to get data from DB.Please let me know if there is any alternate way.

Comment: Can you share what you've done so far?

Comment: I have mentioned the code snippet which I have tried so far in the below url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62523482/unable-to-get-webapi-result-in-controller

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous code during initialization is normal. The whole point of asynchronous code on ASP.NET is so that request threads are freed up to handle other requests. But during initialization, even if you *could* make it asynchronous, you would just be freeing up that thread to... do what, really? It would still have to wait until the initialization is complete before it could start taking requests. So there's no benefit to asynchronous code during application initialization.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. In my case,i need to make db call to get objects.So I was looking for asynchronous code